# How to mock a python function inside another function

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I have the following function in `script.py`:

```
from mock import patch

def outer():
    def inner():
        # something here
        return 5
    return inner() + 2

print(outer())
# 7
```

To test the `outer` function, I'm trying to mock the `inner` function. This is what I have so far:

```
@patch("script.outer.inner")
def test_outer(mock_inner):
    mock_inner.return_value = 10

    result = outer()
    assert result == 12
```

But I keep getting `AttributeError: <function outer at 0x10d594ae8> does not have the attribute 'inner'`. Am I doing something wrong or is this impossible?

Comment: `inner` is not an attribute for `outer`. It's a nested scope. You can't patch it like that. Try patching stuff inside `inner` that needs to be mocked in unit tests.